# В чем разница папок res/values и res/values-v11

Tags: android, android-studio

Чем отличается файл `styles.xml` в папке `values`, от  файла `styles.xml` в папке `values-v11`?

И что из них использует *Android Studio*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Android Studio* использует ВСЕ потому, что это *IDE* - она собирает программу, а не выполняет ее.

А вот конкретное устройство, на котором запущено приложение, только те из ресурсов с квалификаторами (*-v11* в вашем случае квалификатор версии SDK), которые подходят именно этому устройству. Вам нужно [срочно ознакомиться с назначением квалификаторов](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) при выборе альтернативных (наиболее подходящих под текущее устройство, на котором запущено приложение) ресурсов.

Конкретно по вашему вопросу.
Файл стилей (и все прочие файлы в этой папке), который находится в папке */res/values-v11/* будет использоваться для устройств (смартфонов, планшетов и пр.) на которых установлено *SDK11* или выше (*Android 3.0 Honeycomb* и новее).
То, что находится в папке `/res/values/` - ресурсы по умолчанию (без каких-либо квалификаторов), они будут использоваться для устройств, к которым [не удалось выбрать ресурсы с квалификаторами](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch). В вашем случае на всех устройствах с версией андроид меньше *Android 3.0 Honeycomb* (*API 10* и менее).

Этот материал нужно усвоить очень серьезно, потому что это одна из основ андроид-разработки (правильная поддержка фрагментации устройств)

Comment: Спасибо. Но еще один вопрос: я использую API 15 и выше. Почему, если я удаляю values-v11 — в манифесте выскакивает ошибка?

Comment: Потому что квалификатор -v11 для API11 и выше, API15 тоже сюда входит. Очевидно в стиле, который вы удаляете находится тема, которая используется для этих API.

Answer (score 3):

Эти директории указывают, что надо использовать разные стили в зависимости от версии SDK.

Если у вас там всего 2 папки `values-v11` и `values`, тогда:

`values-v11` будут использоваться, если SDK версии 11 и выше

`values` для остальных случаев

Так же там могут быть ресурсы для разных размеров экрана.
Например `values-sw600dp` для экранов с 600dp и больше